# Java ExecutorService is rejecting task even though there should be a worker thread waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, runnable

I got
the following exception on my ExecutorService.

```
Exception in thread "ABC" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:
Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@3e77f807[Not completed, task = 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@4c5029[Wrapped task = 
XYZRunnable@1dd3bf53]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@7a4b2e39
[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 11]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at ...
```

My code looks like this (simplified):

```
final int nThreads = 4;

...

final ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, nThreads,
                                        60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(),
                                        Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());

...

for (int i = 0; i < nThreads - 1; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new XYZRunnable());
}
Future<?> f = executorService.submit(new XYZRunnable());

try {
            f.get(secondsUntilTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            ...
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
            ...
}

return ...;
```

My ExecutorService should have 4 worker threads, so it should also not be a problem to submit/execute 4 runnables.
Why is the exception even thrown at all?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in execute and see why reject is being called.

Comment: Could you double check if any of these XYZRunnable is timing out by any chance? The error you see usually happens when the executor service times out one of the tasks you submitted, either via execute or submit.

Comment: You were right! I did a Thread Dump in VisualVM and saw that one of the workers was waiting forever on one of my exchangers. Not sure what is causing that but I'll find out...